# Open non-modal window from modal window on ios

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Is it possible to open non-modal window (setting `modal` property of a window to `false`) from modal window using titanium on ios7? Right now when I create new non-model window from modal window and try to open it nothing happens. If I set the modal property to `true` than the window is opened properly.

Here is a very simple example (alloy app):

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
function doClick(e) {
    var modal = Alloy.createController('modal').getView();
    modal.open();
}

$.index.open();
```

**modal.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window modal="false" backgroundColor="green">
        <Button title="Open red window" onClick="openWin"></Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**modal.js**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

function openWin() {
    var win = Alloy.createController('win').getView();
    win.open();
}
```

**win.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window modal="false" backgroundColor="red">
        <Label text="I am red window"></Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

So in `modal.xml` if you replace `modal="false"` with `modal="true"` the red window doesn't open any more!

Comment: Could you plz share code?

Comment: Code example added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you insist on opening a modal ontop of a modal, then change the second window to a view and just add it to the modal and then you can open multiple windows/views on top of a modal

Comment: Opening modal from modal window works fine. I want to open non-modal window from modal. Changing window as a view may work but it's far from being an ideal solution I guess...

Comment: why is it far from ideal? I you look at the source code for the CODESTRONG app, it was just a series of views opening and closing to give the illusion of windows... "ideal" is kinda of open-ended... either way, the solution I suggested will work

Comment: After examining the source code of CODESTRONG I think there is nothing wrong with using views instead of windows. Thanks for the idea.